# Gin Index not being used when searching in JSONB column (PostgreSQL) with an array of search terms

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column called `myContent` and one of the objects inside the JSON of each row looks like this:

```
  "metadata": {
    "key": "key",
    "teamBased": false,
  }
```

I want to select all rows that have `teamBased` as false.
This is how  my query looks like:

```
set enable_seqscan=false;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM table n
WHERE n.key = 'key'
AND myContent @> ALL(array[:searchTerms]::jsonb[]));
```

I send `searchTerms` as an array from my Java application and in this case that array looks like this:

```
 ['{"metadata":{"teamBased":false}}']
```

I've created a GIN index that looks like this:

```
  create index "myIndex"
    on myTable using gin (myContent);
```

When I look at the output of `explain analyze query` I see that it's not using my index. However, if I change my query to this

```
set enable_seqscan=false;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM table n
WHERE n.key = 'key'
AND myContent @> '{"metadata":{"teamBased":false}}';
```

it does use it, so I'm assuming it has a problem with the array of search terms that I have in my original query. However, I really need to have the query like that because this query is used in other cases too, when I need more than one search term.

What could be the problem with this? Also, how can I modify my GIN index to not be set to the entire JSON, but rather in one of the objects, for example `metadata`?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you are comparing that using an array if you only have a single element.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I only have a single element in this particular case. In other cases, I have more than one. I reuse the same query in all cases. Isn't this index supposed to work if I have more than one search term?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I'm not sure what you mean with "the column only contains a single element". If I have some rows with the json that I have added in my question, then the where clause in the query would look like this:
`@> ALL(array['{"metadata":{"teamBased":false}}', '{"metadata":{"key":"key"}}']::jsonb[])`
and it works just fine. it selects all rows that in their json have the key with value "key" and `teamBased` as false. So, it basically matches both these search terms.

Comment: Did you try to unnest the array and join?

Comment: @clamp I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide a piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIN indexes don't support `@> ALL`, only `@>`.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) says:

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with top-level key-exists operators `?`, `?&` and `?|` operators and path/value-exists operator `@>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is really helpful. I decided to change the query to only use @> and the index is being used now, however, the query is still really slow (it takes ~4s and I have around 20k rows). Can I do something to speed it up?

Comment: That would be a different question. Make sure to include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.